# how to send information from mobile NFC to RFID-RC522 module?

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid, hce

I have a RFID-RC522 module that is connected to arduino micro. I want to send data from NFC of android mobile to that module. is that possible ? and if so, how can I perform that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, this reader barely supports reading/writing to Mifare Classic cards

It does not support Host Card Emulation or Peer to Peer or other standard cards.

A better module based on PN532 chip would be possible.

Check out https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

Comment: is it possible to get the ID that NFC of my android device is generating?it is generating something random each time.